# Is it Possible to restrict a user on one page HTML content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new in PHP. I have a code file which contain php and html code. In my code i print an HTML page by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.print();
   </script>
```

I use some CSS for my print page like i set page size etc. But problem is that if content on the page is increase its result will be destroy of formatting of page. I want to restrict that content will be on only ONE page. Is it possible?

My CSS

```
<style>
 body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        font: 12pt "Tahoma";
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page {
        width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        padding: 20mm;
        margin: 8mm auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    }
    .subpage {
        padding: 1cm;
        border: 5px solid;
        height: 257mm;
        outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
    }

    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;        
        }
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
        hr { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
border-top: 2px solid #009;
} 
    }


</style>
```

Comment: The increase in content will always result in increase in page, just like any text editor pages. The issue is in `destruction of page formatting`. I'll say use good css codes (responsive). Thanks & Regards

Comment: @Sanjeev after too much searching i use CSS code. If you say i can post my css also.

Comment: it'll be good if you can share the css-html-js in jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: @Sanjeev this css is also on jsfiddle

Comment: @sunny where is the jsfiddle link? Also i am not sure what are you trying to do. print all contents in one page?

Comment: @Aaron http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/2wk6Q/1949/

Comment: @Aaron i actually i do this just like in given link. But i want to restrict my content on one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word counting ... I'm just breaking it up on spaces so it obviously isn't going to be an exact science but it will probably work for most cases.

```
<script>
    (function($){ 
        $(function(){  //document.ready        
            var data = $("#myContent").text();
            var arr = data.split(' ');
            var count = arr.length;
            runResize(count);
            $( window ).resize(runResize(count));
        });  /end document ready

        function runResize(count) {
            if (count > 500) {
                $("#myContent").css('font-size', '90%');
            } else if (count > 1000) {
                $("#myContent").css('font-size', '80%');
            } else if (count > 1500) {
                // etc..
            } else {
                $("#myContent").css('font-size', '100%');
            }
        };
    })(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Comment: How to call this function?

Comment: Just add it to document ready without the first line `$(function() {`  or the last line `});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83387/discussion-between-sunny-and-notorious-pet0).

Answer (score -1):

Create the following .htaccess file under "static-files":

```
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 000.000.000.000
```

Comment: Anil How i can create it? can you give me some refrence link or code please?

Comment: create a folder 'static' and paste all your css and images etc. then create .htaccess file and paste that above code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if((!isset($_SESSION['username']))&&(!isset($_SESSION['name']))&&(!isset($_SESSION['role']))){      // if there is no valid session
    header("Location: login.html");
}
if($_SESSION['role']=='1'){
    $login=$_SESSION['name'];
}
if($_SESSION['role']=='0'){
    $login='Hello '.$_SESSION['name'].' you have successufully logged in as User!';
}
?>
```

- Use Sessions for such kind of restriction.
- Authoriz the user by checking its type
- If unauthorized then redirect them to some error dispaying page.